# Graph verticles counting

Tags: combinatorics

We create  a graph in the following way.First we create edges A and B(which have no verticle) then we create edges $a_{1}$ and $b_{1}$.There is no verticle between the pair but each one can have verticle to both A,B only one (A or B) or none .Then we create $a_{2}$ and $b_{2}$ there is no verticle between them but they can have verticle to any of the previous four edges .Continuing we create pairs which have no common verticle but they can be connected to the others.The last pair is $a_{4}$ $b_{4}$.Between 2 edges there is only one verticle.At the end it turns out that
everyone except A have diffrent degree of verticles.What is the amount of verticles of A?

Comment: Would this look more like a graph if we translate edge to vretex and link to edge?

Comment: yes it is the same

Comment: Samit, please edit your Question to use "vertex" for nodes and "edge" for links.  It is too confusing to have "verticles" for links and "edges" for nodes (as you seemingly have phrased the original post).  You state that all nodes(?) "except A" have different degrees (number of edges?).  This seems to allow node A to have the same degree as some other node, but it is unclear if you are insisting it *must* have the same degree as some other node.

Comment: edited and yes this is what I state